# Перемещение элемента по кривой Безье по клику в обе стороны

Tags: javascript, css3, svg, анимация, svg-animation

Имеются две точки (`A` и `B`) и кривая Безье от одной к другой. При клике на точку `A` мы запускаем с помощью `animateMotion` анимацию перемещения элемента вдоль пути движения из точки `A` к точке `B`.

```html
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="300" viewBox="15 15 150 50">

  <circle id="a" cx="26.5" cy="13.2" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  <circle id="b" cx="87.3" cy="23.8" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  
  <text y="15" x="18" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">A</text>
  <text y="26" x="92" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">B</text>

  <path d="m 26.458333,13.229167 c 2.776366,16.871891 9.790064,18.199908 18.520833,13.229166 L 63.499999,13.229167 C 77.382834,4.1082137 88.663388,0.52362484 87.312499,23.8125 v 0" stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="1" fill="none" id="mPath"></path>
  
  <circle id="c" cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="green">
    <animateMotion begin="a.click" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze">
      <mpath xlink:href="#mPath"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  
</svg>
```

**Вопрос:** Как мне реализовать дополнительную анимацию, а именно при клике на точку `B` запустить анимацию перемещения элемента вдоль пути движения из точки `B` к точке `A`? Чтобы не запутаться, поясняю задачу более подробно:

1. При клике на точку `A` мы запускаем анимацию перемещения элемента вдоль пути движения из точки `A` к точке `B`.
2. При клике на точку `B` мы запускаем анимацию перемещения элемента вдоль пути движения из точки `B` к точке `A`.
3. Это не реверс. Это ни туда-обратно. Обе анимации независимы и не связаны друг с другом. Их связывает исключительно только путь (`path`) между точками.

В связи с чем возникает вполне предсказуемый **вопрос:** Если путь (`path`) у них один, то для анимации из точки `B` к точке `A` необходимо добавить дополнительно такой же путь? Но, если у существующего уже есть начальная точка, конечная точка, отрезок, и всё это ведет от точки `A` к точке `B`, то как нарисовать такой же путь (`path`), чтобы он вел в обратную сторону, и при этом не сбиться с координатами?

Интересует подробное описание такой реализации и сама реализация любыми средствами и технологиями, указанными в метках вопроса, а это может быть и `CSS`, и `SMIL SVG`, а также с помощью и `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но, если у существующего уже есть начальная точка, конечная точка,
> отрезок, и всё это ведет от точки A к точке B, то как нарисовать такой
> же путь (path), чтобы он вел в обратную сторону, и при этом не сбиться
> с координатами?

Можно нарисовать два пути от `А=>В` и от `В=>А` и это будет самое простое решение, только их надо рисовать из разных начальных точек `А` И `B`

Анимация вдоль пути `animateMotion` всегда начинается **по умолчанию** из начальной точки
`<path d="M"..`

Но есть более простой путь изменить начало движения не от начальной точки, а от конечной  к началу: `keyPoints="1;0.5;0"` `keyTimes="0;0.5;1"` при нулевом времени `keyTimes="0` движение начинается с конца  `keyPoints="1`

Используя эти знания можно повесить на один объект две анимации  `А=>В` и от `В=>А` по одному пути. Каждая анимация будет запускаться по клику соответствующих окружностях.

```html
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="300" viewBox="15 15 150 50">

  <circle id="a" cx="26.5" cy="13.2" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  <circle id="b" cx="87.3" cy="23.8" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  
  <text y="15" x="18" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">A</text>
  <text y="26" x="92" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">B</text>

  <path d="m 26.458333,13.229167 c 2.776366,16.871891 9.790064,18.199908 18.520833,13.229166 L 63.499999,13.229167 C 77.382834,4.1082137 88.663388,0.52362484 87.312499,23.8125 v 0" stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="1" fill="none" id="mPath"></path>
  
  <circle id="c" cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="green" pointer-events="none">
        <!-- Анимация из пункта А в пункт В    -->   
   <animateMotion begin="a.click" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze">
      <mpath xlink:href="#mPath"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>  
          <!-- Анимация из пункта В в пункт А    --> 
      <animateMotion begin="b.click" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" keyPoints="1;0.5;0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="linear">
      <mpath xlink:href="#mPath"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  
</svg>
```

В примере ниже два объекта: зеленый и красный шарик, которые перемещаются по одному и тому же пути, но запускаются соответственно кликами по разным отправным точкам `А` и `В`

```html
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="300" viewBox="15 15 150 50">

  <circle  id="a" cx="26.5" cy="13.2" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  <circle  id="b" cx="87.3" cy="23.8" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  
  <text y="15" x="18" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">A</text>
  <text y="26" x="92" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">B</text>

  <path d="m 26.458333,13.229167 c 2.776366,16.871891 9.790064,18.199908 18.520833,13.229166 L 63.499999,13.229167 C 77.382834,4.1082137 88.663388,0.52362484 87.312499,23.8125 v 0" stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="1" fill="none" id="mPath"></path>
    
        <!-- Анимация из пункта А в пункт В    -->
  <circle id="c" cx="" cy="" r="4" fill="green" pointer-events="none">
    <animateMotion begin="a.click" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze">
      <mpath xlink:href="#mPath"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>  
   </circle>    
             <!-- Анимация из пункта В в пункт А    -->
     <circle id="e" cx="" cy="" r="4" fill="red" pointer-events="none">
      <animateMotion begin="b.click" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" keyPoints="1;0.5;0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="linear">
      <mpath xlink:href="#mPath"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  
</svg>
```